# How to set ImageView rounded corners programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, mobile

i'm new in Android Studio. I want to ask, can i make ImageView with round corners programmatically? because i want use it to load data from database. So, user profile picture will be appear with rounded corner

[image: this is what i want]

my XML is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#F3FFFC">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profilepicture"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for your time to read my question, hope i can solve this problem :D

Comment: by using cardview

Comment: i have tried, but i'm not able to do that

Comment: not appear the profilepicture, i have set background profile picture and set corner radius.. but blank :(

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

by using this dependency `implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'`